# bootstrap 3 datetimepicker custom year

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need a calendar popup for my project and I just want to show years just like this. (2000 - 2009)

[image]

I found this library [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and it seems easy. Then I've configured it to show years. Worked fine.

[image]

**But I want to show 2000-2009 range in dropdown.** That's the problem. I used "viewMode" option to show years. But I couldn't find anywhere to show custom year range. Here is my js code. And here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/5deat3wL/) for live example. Any solution?

```
$(function () {
 $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
 viewMode: 'years',
 format: 'L'                
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
 viewMode: 'years',
 defaultDate : '2005-01-01',
 format: 'L'                
 });
```

set

> defaultDate : '2005-01-01'

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5deat3wL/2/)

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Can't imagine why. Could you please update the jsfiddle?

Comment: Ah your code disabled years back in 2000 Not showing 2000 - 2009 when someone click the dropdown.

Comment: @CssSY ok will look into your jsFiddle

Comment: Wow. We came very near. But it showing 1995 - 2006 ;(

Comment: No any luck ..?

Comment: @CssSY please upvote my answer and accept the answer